# tomiki-aikido tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Tomiki named his "style" (in as much as he named it) *Shodokan* -- References [here](http://homepage2.nifty.com/shodokan/en/name.html) and [here](http://homepage2.nifty.com/shodokan/en/aisatsu.html).  So, I suggest we add a couple of synonymous tags: [tomiki-aikido](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomiki-aikido), [sports-aikido](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports-aikido), and [shodokan-aikido](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shodokan-aikido).  Or should we have them as [aikido-xxx](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aikido-xxx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shudder at Aikido-XXX, which sounds like a porn movie. *Pardon me while I go and try to bleach away the images produced by that tag.*

There is a part of me that does not want to emphasize the distinction between *aikido* and *shodokan aikido*; I don't perceive what I received from my Yoshinkan school as essentially distinct from what I receive from my current Tomiki instructor.  I would treat them all as synonyms I recognize that there are many who perceive them as fundamentally distinct.  I would prefer to use the [aikido](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aikido) for all aikido, and reserve [shodokan-aikido](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shodokan-aikido) for material that is specific to the Tomiki lineage.

I'm not entirely sure we have enough relevant discussion to justify the number of synonyms, but in a spirit of hope, I suppose I can endorse the idea.

Comment: **Rule 34**: There are **no** exceptions.  [Aikido is like S&M](http://www.aikidofaq.com/humor/top10/index.html)

Comment: Now I need to go find another bottle of bleach and immerse my brain. By the rules on that page, I must now thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Until we have a problematically large set of aikido questions with a substantial subset of Tomiki questions, I think overoptimizing is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Why do we need [aikido-shodokan](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aikido-shodokan) when the question can simply be tagged as [aikido](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aikido)[shodokan](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shodokan)?

IOW it doesn't bother me that two tags are used, which negates the need for a specific tag to be created. The tag [aikido-whateverstyle](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aikido-whateverstyle) would also look a bit disjointed unless there were enough variants to make it look normal.

Comment: Shodokan just means !open way" … [Does it makes sense to have it as a tag?](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/496/82)