# Should the Shodokan tag exist?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

There are [3 questions tqagged as `shodokan`](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shodokan), all to do with the Aikido style that Tomiki developed. [Previously](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/tomiki-aikido-tag), it was agreed that breaking down Aikido styles in tags was unnecessary.

However, shodokan means "open way" and is used in both Aikido and Karate that I know off. Thus does it make sense to have a tag which means 2open way"?

Currently, the tag has no information and thus could become whatever we chose it to be.

[I expended the tag](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tags/shodokan/info). Does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It should exist.

In that case someone needs to write a proper description of it.

Comment: Down (Up) vote if you disagree (agree)…

Comment: I feel the tag does add value in that it helps address different styles within Aikido.  Perhaps two different tags of  Shodokan(Aikido) and Shodokan(Karate) may help clarify things

Answer (score 2):

As someone who has not studied aikido, I find the Shodokan school of thought to be rather distinct from other varieties.

I have always seen [Shotokan karate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotokan) and [Shodokan aikido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shodokan_Aikido) romanized distinctly. According to Wikipedia, at least, these are different characters. Is there a different Shodokan term applied to karate as well?

Comment: I do not speak enough Japanese to tell to be honest.

Answer (score -1):

## It should NOT exist

In that case, all questions should be de-tagged.

Comment: Down (Up) vote if you disagree (agree)…